# How to enable css modules only for .mod.css files ? Nextjs

Tags: webpack, next.js, css-modules

There are two kind of styling files i use in my project `.css` files & `.mod.css` files. I want to enable CSS modules only for the files whose extension is `*.mod.css`.

My `next.config.js` file

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({
      cssModules:true,
      cssLoaderOptions: {
        localIdentName: "[local]_[hash:base64:5]",
      },
      webpack(config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.mod.css$/,
        })
        return config
      }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As of the fact that `withCss` next's plugin defines the css loaders you will need to **modify** it instead of adding a new one.

```js
// next.config.js

const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
  },
  webpack(config, options) {

    config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
      if (rule.test.toString().includes('.css')) {
        rule.rules = rule.use.map(useRule => {
          if (typeof useRule === 'string') {
            return {
              loader: useRule,
            };
          }
          if (useRule.loader.startsWith('css-loader')) {
            return {
              oneOf: [
                {
                  test: /\.mod\.css$/,
                  loader: useRule.loader,
                  options: {
                    ...useRule.options,
                    modules: true,
                  },
                },
                {
                  loader: useRule.loader,
                  options: {
                    ...useRule.options,
                    modules: false,
                  },
                },
              ],
            };
          }

          return useRule;
        });

        delete rule.use;
      }
    });    


    return config;
  },
});
```

This code looks for the `withCss` config, and modifies the rules to use webpack's [`oneOf`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleoneof) option.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution, in `next.config.js`. It allows use of css modules and global stylesheets, and is customizable.

This takes a file called `components/Layout/index.module.scss` containing a class called `.container` and transforms it into the class name `Layout__container--cF6H8`. Obviously your file structure or needs may be different, but this is flexible and customizable

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

...

const nextConfig = {
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    getLocalIdent: (loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
      const filePath = loaderContext.resourcePath;
      const fileBaseName = path.basename(filePath);

      if (/\.module\.scss$/.test(fileBaseName)) {
        const modulePathParts = filePath.split('/');

        const moduleName = modulePathParts[modulePathParts.length - 2];

        return `${moduleName}__${localName}--${crypto
          .createHash('sha1')
          .update(filePath)
          .digest('base64')
          .slice(0, 5)}`;
      }

      return localName;
    },

    ...
```